# How to link to the README_FOR_APP and readme documentation in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, static, documentation

This should be a simple problem I think, I have all my Rails documentation inside the doc/app directory, which I can manually load and view in my browser. I want to just link to this documentation from another view. I have tried to very simply make another controller that will open the static HTML readme pages.

```
class DocController < ApplicationController
  def show
      open ("/doc/app/doc/README_FOR_APP.html")
  end
end
```

And I've tried the above with various variations. That page gets loaded, but with no CSS styling applied, and trying to link to the various pages pops up an error, indicating the app expects an action for each page I'm trying to link to.

It seems like the approach I'm on will be very tedious to actually implement. Making an action for every page sounds like a bad choice. Is there an easier way?

In case its not clear, everything was documented automatically using

```
rake doc:app
```

Answer (score 0):

the doc directory is not going to be served up by your web server, but you could sym link `#{Rails.root}/public/docs` -> `#{Rails.root}/doc` and then it would be accessible at `http://localhost:3000/docs`

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I have tried the symbolic link, and the result is the same. A single page with no CSS and no linkability

Comment: What does the css path look like?

Comment: I believe it is all relative to the static page. Using something like "../rdoc.css". Which is probably breaking since I'm trying to render that from the "app/views/doc/show" page I think?